# How to initialize a listbox to a desired starting point in the list?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I created a macro for Excel which opens a list of all visible sheets in a workbook and goes to the desired sheet as you scroll through the list. The idea is to avoid using the mouse as much as possible.

[image: Here is a screenshot of how it looks]

I am forced to scroll *down* starting from the first item in the list.
I would like to instead "start" from the initial sheet (*wherever it may be*) so I can scroll up/down depending on what sheet I would like to open.

In other words,

1. I would like the listbox to populate with all visible sheets
2. I would like the starting point for the user to be the active sheet so they can scroll up/down from their starting point

Code for the listbox:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload ListBox
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        ListBox1.AddItem WS.Name
    Next WS
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
End Sub
```

Code which opens the listbox:

```vb
Public Sub ShowUserForm()
    Load ListBox
    ListBox.Show
    Debug.Print "===="
    Debug.Print
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another one...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet, idx As Long

    With Me.ListBox1
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                .AddItem ws.Name
                If ws Is ActiveSheet Then
                    idx = .ListCount - 1 ' item indexes start at zero
                End If
            End If
        Next
        .ListIndex = idx  ' 
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
End Sub
```

You mentioned "all . . . sheets", if you want to include Chart sheets loop Each objSheet in Sheets and in the change event replace Worksheets with Sheets

Comment: Thank you; works perfectly as required. I will keep in mind the list index solution in the future. This will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

what's about that:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim wksTab As Worksheet

 For Each wksTab In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  If wksTab.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
   If wksTab.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
     Me.ListBox1.AddItem wksTab.Name
   End If
  End If

 Next wksTab
 Me.ListBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.Name
 Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

End Sub
```

Best regards
Bernd

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For some reason, the list wasn't capturing all sheets and I was encountering a "subscript out of range" error but it was indeed initializing at the active sheet.

Comment: i could send you the file, if you want.